# sherlockNavigationDrawer missing references?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to build a project using the `sherlockNavigationDrawer`. However, it seems I am missing references that should be in the *resources* folder. These errors pop up in `SherlockActionBarDrawerToggleCompat.java`. In particular these sections have broken references.

```
private static final int[] THEME_ATTRS = new int[] {
    **R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator**
};
...
if (home == null) {
    home = activity.findViewById(R.id.abs__home);
    homeRes = **R.id.abs__home**;
}
```

I don't know if I am missing some file or if the `sherlockNavigationDrawer` doesn't natively have these values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use actionbarsherlock you have the navigation drawer and support library for backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial. The navigation drawer works just fine: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/